# 2 Errors affect app publishing in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I'm getting 2 errors even though App is working fine on simulator. Will these errors cause problem when publishing on google play store and ios App store?

First one:

```
 warning: The include file 'package:flutter_lints/flutter.yaml' in 'C:\Users\codingaccount\Desktop\myApp\analysis_options.yaml' can't be found when analyzing 'C:\Users\codingaccount\Desktop\myApp'. (include_file_not_found at [myApp] analysis_options.yaml:10)
```

Second one:

```
Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\contacts_service-0.6.3\android\src\main\java\flutter\plugins\contactsservice\contactsservice\ContactsServicePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

Comment: There is a good discussion on github regarding this issue, and you are facing it because of differences in IDE.https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/86917

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we should know why we are facing anything so this,

The flutter_lints wouldn't work if you `analysis_options.yaml` contains

```
include: package:lints/recommended.yaml

linter:
  rules:
    - avoid_print
    - avoid_unnecessary_containers
    - avoid_web_libraries_in_flutter
    - no_logic_in_create_state
    - prefer_const_constructors
    - prefer_const_constructors_in_immutables
    - prefer_const_declarations
    - prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
    - sized_box_for_whitespace
    - use_full_hex_values_for_flutter_colors
    - use_key_in_widget_constructors
```

Here is the link to discussion https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/86917

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think so that warning will crash your app.
And for the first one, I think you miss the rule in the analysis_options file.